# How could a linked list achieve O(n log n) sorting time?

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, time-complexity

I'm curious, in the first place, why `std::list` and `std::forward_list` include sorting functions as member functions, unlike every other standard library container. But what's more interesting to me is that both [CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/sort) and [CPlusPlus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/sort/) claim that this sorting is done in O(*n* log *n*) time.

I can't even imagine how one would sort a container without random access to elements. So I threw together a test, using `forward_list` to make it as difficult as possible.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <deque>
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using std::endl;
using namespace std::chrono;

typedef nanoseconds::rep length_of_time;
constexpr int TEST_SIZE = 25000;


class Stopwatch
{
    public:
        void start_timing();
        void end_timing();
        length_of_time get_elapsed_time() const;
    private:
        time_point<high_resolution_clock> start;
        time_point<high_resolution_clock> end;
        length_of_time elapsed_time = 0;
};


void Stopwatch::start_timing()
{
    start = high_resolution_clock::now();
}


void Stopwatch::end_timing()
{
    end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = end - start;
    auto elapsed_nanoseconds = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(elapsed);
    elapsed_time = elapsed_nanoseconds.count();
}


length_of_time Stopwatch::get_elapsed_time() const
{
    return elapsed_time;
}


std::mt19937_64 make_random_generator()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto random_generator = std::mt19937_64();
    auto current_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto nanos = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(
            current_time.time_since_epoch()).count();
    random_generator.seed(nanos);
    return random_generator;
}


int main()
{
    Stopwatch timer;
    std::deque<length_of_time> times;
    auto generator = make_random_generator();
    for (int i = 1; i <= TEST_SIZE; i++) {
        std::forward_list<uint64_t> container;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            container.push_front(generator());
        }
        timer.start_timing();
        container.sort();
        timer.end_timing();
        times.push_back(timer.get_elapsed_time());
        container.clear();
    }

    for (const auto& time: times) {
        std::cout << time << endl;
    }
}
```

The numbers this program output gave the following graph:

[image: forward list sorting time]

Which does indeed look like O(*n* log *n*) growth (although the spikes at each third of the way across are interesting). How does the library do this? Perhaps copy to a container that supports sorting, sort that, and copy back?

Comment: a version of merge sort that does the `conquering` part before the `divide`. Known as bottom-up mergesort

Comment: @Smac89 I know what mergesort is, and your point explains it better than the answers.

Comment: @Smac89 - a bottom up merge sort still does the divide step first, by either considering a list of "n" elements to be "n" runs of size 1, or by considering any element followed by an out of order element to be the end of a run to take advantage of natural ordering in a list.

Comment: Put linked list in other container: O(n) time, sort other container: O(n log n), put other container in linked list: O(n). Time complexity O(n)+O(n log n)+O(n) = O(n log n)

Comment: no need to actually divide into sublists. have `log2(n)` steps in a loop. on `k`-th step, have two pointers, 2nd `2^k` elements ahead of the 1st, initially. merge the two chunks (each of size `2^k` initially) relinking the resulting nodes one by one at the end of the resulting list. repeat until all `n` elements are processed. go on merging the `2^(k+1)`-sized chunks of this result, used as input now, as the next step in the overall `log2(n)` loop.

Comment: How to create such graph showing `value of n` versus `runtime`? Any hints..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Linked lists can be sorted in *O(n log n)* using [Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Interestingly, since linked lists already have the appropriate structure, sorting a linked list with Mergesort only requires *O(1)* extra space.

The fact that this requires a specialized algorithm specifically tuned for the list structure is also the reason `sort` is a member function of the list, rather than a separate function.

---

As for how it works - all you need is the merge operation. The merge operation takes two lists. You look at the heads of both lists, and remove the smallest head and append it to your result list. You keep doing this until all heads have been merged into the big list - done.

Here's a sample merge operation in C++:

```
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    int val;
};

Node* merge(Node* a, Node* b) {
    Node fake_head(nullptr, 0);

    Node* cur = &fake_head;
    while (a && b) {
        if (a->val < b->val) { cur->next = a; a = a->next; }
        else                 { cur->next = b; b = b->next; }
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    cur->next = a ? a : b;
    return fake_head.next;
}
```

Comment: How would you get the two lists in the first place? I know how mergesort works, but wouldn't you need a further O(*n*) time to access every node individually and then start merging them?

Comment: @EMBLEM You work from the bottom-up, linking up single elements, then two elements, then four, etc. You can constantly use the links you've found previously to not require random access.

Comment: Even without the bottom-up, the O(n) time to split the list into two is no worse than the O(n) time needed anyway to merge the two lists again. Therefore, each recursive step only costs a constant factor more, and the complexity would still be O(n log n).

Answer (score 4):

Example code of a bottom up merge sort using an array of pointers to lists where array[i] points to a list of size 2^i (except last pointer points to a list of unlimited size). This is how the HP / Microsoft standard template library implements std::list::sort.

```
#define NUMLISTS 32                     /* number of lists */

typedef struct NODE_{
struct NODE_ * next;
int data;                               /* could be any comparable type */
}NODE;

NODE * MergeLists(NODE *, NODE *);

NODE * SortList(NODE *pList)
{
NODE * aList[NUMLISTS];                 /* array of lists */
NODE * pNode;
NODE * pNext;
int i;
    if(pList == NULL)                   /* check for empty list */
        return NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)       /* zero array */
        aList[i] = NULL;
    pNode = pList;                      /* merge nodes into aList[] */
    while(pNode != NULL){
        pNext = pNode->next;
        pNode->next = NULL;
        for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i] != NULL); i++){
            pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
            aList[i] = NULL;
        }
        if(i == NUMLISTS)
            i--;
        aList[i] = pNode;
        pNode = pNext;
    }
    pNode = NULL;                       /* merge array into one list */
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)
        pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
    return pNode;
}

NODE * MergeLists(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2)
{
NODE *pDst = NULL;                      /* destination head ptr */
NODE **ppDst = &pDst;                   /* ptr to head or prev->next */
    while(1){
        if(pSrc1 == NULL){
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            break;
        }
        if(pSrc2 == NULL){
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            break;
        }
        if(pSrc2->data < pSrc1->data){  /* if src2 < src1 */
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            pSrc2 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc2->next));
            continue;
        } else {                        /* src1 <= src2 */
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            pSrc1 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc1->next));
            continue;
        }
    }
    return pDst;
}
```

Another but slower way to merge sort a list is similar to a 4 tape sort (all sequential access). The initial list is split into two lists. Each list is considered to be a stream of runs, where the initial run size is 1. In this example, counters are used to keep track of run boundaries so it's a bit more complicated and slower than the array of pointers method. Runs from two input lists are merged, alternating between two output lists. After each merge pass, the run size is doubled, the direction of the merge is changed so what were output lists become input lists and vice versa. The sort is done when all runs end up on just one of the output lists. If stability is not required, then run boundaries could be defined as any node followed by an out of order node, and this would take advantage of natural ordering with the original list.

```
NODE * SortList(NODE * pList)
{
NODE *pSrc0;
NODE *pSrc1;
NODE *pDst0;
NODE *pDst1;
NODE **ppDst0;
NODE **ppDst1;
int cnt;

    if(pList == NULL)                   /* check for null ptr */
        return NULL;
    if(pList->next == NULL)             /* if only one node return it */
        return pList;
    pDst0 = NULL;                       /* split list */
    pDst1 = NULL;
    ppDst0 = &pDst0;
    ppDst1 = &pDst1;
    while(1){
        *ppDst0 = pList;
        pList = *(ppDst0 = &pList->next);
        if(pList == NULL)
            break;
        *ppDst1 = pList;
        pList = *(ppDst1 = &pList->next);
        if(pList == NULL)
            break;
    }
    *ppDst0 = NULL;
    *ppDst1 = NULL;
    cnt = 1;                            /* init run size */
    while(1){
        pSrc0 = pDst0;                  /* swap merge direction */
        pSrc1 = pDst1;
        pDst0 = NULL;
        pDst1 = NULL;
        ppDst0 = &pDst0;
        ppDst1 = &pDst1;
        while(1){                       /* merge a set of runs */
            if(MergeRuns(&ppDst0, &pSrc0, &pSrc1, cnt))
                break;
            if(MergeRuns(&ppDst1, &pSrc0, &pSrc1, cnt))
                break;
        }
        cnt <<= 1;                      /* bump run size */
        if(pDst1 == NULL)               /* break if done */
            break;
    }
    return pDst0;
}       

int MergeRuns(NODE ***pppDst, NODE **ppSrc0, NODE **ppSrc1, int cnt)
{
NODE **ppDst = *pppDst;
NODE *pSrc0  = *ppSrc0;
NODE *pSrc1  = *ppSrc1;
int cnt0, cnt1;

    cnt0 = cnt;
    cnt1 = cnt;
    if(pSrc0 == NULL){                      /* if end data src0 */
        *ppDst = NULL;
        *pppDst = ppDst;
        return(1);
    }
    if(pSrc1 == NULL){                      /* if end data src1 */
        do{                                 /*   copy rest of src0 */
            *ppDst = pSrc0;
            pSrc0 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc0->next));
        }while(pSrc0);
        *ppDst = NULL;
        *pppDst = ppDst;
        return(1);
    }
    while(1){
        if(pSrc1->data < pSrc0->data){      /* if src1 < src0 */
            *ppDst = pSrc1;                 /*  move src1 */
            pSrc1 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc1->next));
            if(pSrc1 != NULL && --cnt1)     /*  if not end run1, continue */
                continue;
            do{                             /*    copy run0 */
                *ppDst = pSrc0;
                pSrc0 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc0->next));
            }while(pSrc0 != NULL && --cnt0);
            break;
        } else {                            /* else src0 <= src1 */
            *ppDst = pSrc0;                 /*  move src0 */
            pSrc0 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc0->next));
            if(pSrc0 != NULL && --cnt0)     /*  if not end run0, continue */
                continue;
            do{                             /*    copy run1 */
                *ppDst = pSrc1;
                pSrc1 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc1->next));
            }while(pSrc1 != NULL && --cnt1);
            break;
        }
    }
    *ppSrc0 = pSrc0;                        /* update ptrs, return */
    *ppSrc1 = pSrc1;
    *ppDst  = NULL;
    *pppDst = ppDst;
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is O(nlogn) for linked lists. I don't know what the default sort function is for C++, but I suspect its mergesort.

Comment: The important point is mergesort can be written without random access.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the standard here, but [CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/sort) states that the complexity of sort is Nlog(N) **comparisons**. This means that even quick sort would be a standard conforming implementation as it would be Nlog(N) comparisons (but not Nlog(N) time).

Answer (score 0):

You start with an unsorted list of unknown length. Say the elements are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3...

In the first pass, you created two linked lists, each consisting of pairs of numbers in sorted order. List 0 starts with elements 0 and 1 in sorted order. List 1 starts with elements 2 and 3 in sorted order. Elements 4 and 5 are added to List 0 in sorted order, 6 and 7 are added to List 1 and so on. Obviously care must be taken not to overshoot the end of the original list.

In the second pass, you merge these two lists to created two linked lists, each consisting of sets of 4 numbers in sorted order. Each time you combine two elements from List 0 and two elements from List 1. The next smallest element is obviously every time the one at the front of the list.

In the second pass, you merge these lists into two linked lists, each consisting of sets of 8 sorted numbers, then 16, then 32 and so on, until the resulting list would contain n or more numbers. If n = 2^k then there are k = log2 (n) passes, so this takes O (n log n).